# find cumulative number of shops of past 12 month in mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I want to find the cumulative number of shops of past 12 month.

```
Sample Collection
{
  _id: '5f3d4e5e01e06f0007335233',
  name: 'Walmart',
  createdAt: '2020-08-22T17:42:09.908+00:00'
}
```

I am able to get result of new shops of past 12 month

```
Shop.aggregate([{
  $match: {
     createdAt: {
      $gte: {
        $date: {{moment.utc().subtract(12, "months").startOf('day').toISOString()}}
      },
      $lt: {
        $date: {{moment.utc().startOf('day').toISOString()}}
      }
    },
    }
}, {
  $project: {
    dateParts: {
      $dateToParts: { date: '$createdAt' }
    },
    total: true,
  }
}, {
    $group: {
      _id:  {
        month: '$dateParts.month',
        year: '$dateParts.year',
      },
      numShops: { $sum: 1 },
    }
}])
```

And this query returns result something like this

```
[{
  _id: {
    month:3,
    year:2021
  },
  numShops:62,
}, {
.
.
.
}]
```

The above query only returns the new shops of past 12 months, but I want total shops until specific month.

Query must return result something like

```
[{
  date: 'Aug-2020',
  numShops: 100,   // Total number of shops until aug-2020
}, {
  date: 'Sep-2020'
  numShops: 230, // Total number of shops until sep-2020
}, ....
]
```

Comment: Do share how your collection looks like.

Comment: @TusharShahi actually I don't think it matters how collection looks like. I just simply want the count month wise

Comment: So, the date is the creation date of the document?

Comment: Yes, it's creation date. It's actually dummy scenario that I have created.

Comment: have you tried anything, can you show your research? what is the type of date field can you show in what is the format of date in collection?

Comment: @turivishal I have added the details what I have tried and what I want to achieve

Comment: mongodb will not return month as string, you have to convert it externally from number to string after query.

Comment: Yes no problem, I'll do that  externally. I just want to find the total number of shops until that month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB will not return month as string, the efficient option is to do it client side after query,

You can do it in the query to handle some situation,

- `$group` you did correctly operation
- `$arrayElemAt` to select a specific month string from provided `months` array
- `$toString` to convert `year` from number to string
- `$concat` to prepare `date` string

```
let months = ["", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        year: { $year: "$createdAt" },
        month: { $month: "$createdAt" }
      },
      numShops: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      numShops: 1,
      date: {
        $concat: [
          { $arrayElemAt: [months, "$_id.month"] },
          "-",
          { $toString: "$_id.year" }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ysYHKdA_3CX)